# ¿como refrescar los eventos de fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

estoy creando una aplicacion con laravel y fullcalendar y quiero que al darle a un boton cree un evento nuevo y lo dej ver de inmediato, ya pude hacer que lo cree sin problemas, la cuestion es que no se actualiza hasta que recargue la pagina. este es mi codigo :

```
$('#guardar').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
     url:"/calendar/crear",
     type:"POST",
      data:$("#formulario_guardar").serialize(),
   }).done(function(uno){
     $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
   });
```

no se actualiza, si alguien sabe porque le agradezco mucho la informacion.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código completo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes utilizar render de fullcalendar

Algo así:

```
$("#TuCalendario").fullCalendar('render');
```

Espero te ayude, Saludos!

Answer (score -2):

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
     title: 'Sin Atencion',
     start: start,
     end: end,
     backgroundColor:'red',
     color: 'red',
     TextColor: 'black',
     borderColor: 'red'
 });

despues del modal hide coloca ese codigo con los datos de tu evento